# Sending Mail With Javax but receiver "MAILER-DAEMON" as sender

Tags: java, android, sendmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use javax to send emails programmatically.

I followed steps on answer of the following question: Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)  and it works fine. I just changed mail server to "smtp.yandex.com.tr"

When i send/receive email with this code it writes "MAILER-DAEMON" in sender section. How can I fix this?

By the way I make also authentication with a yandex mail to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this with adding from part. I was thinking just giving sender was ok but apperantly i had to specify "from" as follows

```
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
```